# javascript return from php no updating anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hard to explain in the title...

So i have a form which is validated via javascript and an ajax request is sent to a php page which if succesful inputs the data and sets the database response.

However, on the ajax call getting the correct repsonse it doesnt carry out what i wish it to...

I What i want to happen is when the php returns a success JSON return, the .commentsdiv is reloaded.

This doesnt work however. But the comments are added into the database.

here is the code

part of commentsbox div and form:

```
<div class="commentsbox">
        <form class="addcomment" action="process/addcomment.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" class="postid" name="postid" value="'.$postID.'">
        <input type="hidden" class="usernameuser" name="usernameuser" value="'.$usernameuser.'">
        <input type="hidden" class="userid" name="userid" value="'.$userid.'">

        <input type="text" name="addpostcomment" class="addpostcomment" placeholder="Add Comment..." />
        <input type="submit" id="addcommentbutton" value="Post" />
        <br />
        <br />
        </form>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

The viewbuild.php url is dynamic depending on what post is viewed. Do i need it to be like viewbuild.php?id=1 etc? Because that doesnt work niether.

```
    // JavaScript - Edit Post

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addcomment").submit(function(){
    var $targetForm = $(this);

    $targetForm.find(".error").remove();
    $targetForm.find(".success").remove();

    // If there is anything wrong with 
    // validation we set the check to false
    var check = true;

    // Get the value of the blog update post
    var $comment = $targetForm.find('.addpostcomment'),
        newcomment = $comment.val();

    // Validation
    if (newcomment == '') {
        check = false;
       $comment.after('<br><br><br><div class="error">Text Is Required</div>');
    }

  // ... goes after Validation
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process/addcomment.php",
data: $targetForm.serialize(),
dataType: "json",
success: function(response){
    if (response.databaseSuccess) {
        $('.commentsbox').load('viewbuild.php');
    }
    else {
        $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');
    }
}
});
    return false;
});
});
```

Here is part end of php:

```
$return['databaseSuccess'] = $dbSuccess;

echo json_encode($return);
```

Any help is most appreciated! :)

Comment: "So i have a form which is validated via javascript"... client-side validation only is **BAD**

Comment: once i get the basic code functioning as i want i will make sure everything is secure after as its not a live site currently :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your php response is setting the proper headers.  You need to set the content type as "application/json" for JQuery to call the success function.  Try adding debugging to the error or complete callbacks when you call the jquery ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

well , why am i thinking that you should check what value the obj returns ..

i mean ..

```
if(response.databaseSuccess == ??! ) { ... }
```

Or why don't you just check for the length of the retruned string.

```
if(response.databaseSuccess.length > 3){ alert('ok');}
```

One advise bro, if you are returning JUST one parameter  .. use e string ..  not JSON .. ;)
so, in php you would have :

```
echo $databaseSuccess;
```

And in JS ..  the IF wil be more simple :

```
 if(response == "ok"){ alert('ok');}
```

Get it ?

Hope i've helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will be needing more than one parameter in the future i believe.

Just tried doing  if(response.databaseSuccess.length > 3){   alert('ok');}  

but no even an alert comes up when submitting...

Comment: use ` console.log(response); ` to see whats going on with the response and it will say to you if there is a mistake. Otherwise .. well, check you php file .. andd check this .. DATA that you are sending .. it dosn't look like much, but it could be a big problem, trust me .. ;d

Comment: All the data is being sent correct and im getting the databaseSuccess: true response.

Ahh confusing now lol.

Comment: in this case did you try `if(response.databaseSuccess == true){ .. }`, just asking .. :)